# Laravel 5.2 Model properties aren't changing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Working on a new project that involves converting video files from MPEG to WEBM. My issue is that in the conversion process, I'm trying to update my `Video` model properties, but for some reason I can't modify some of the properties.

For example, I can modify the `name` of the Video model, but I can't modify the `streampath` or `converted` fields

```
class Video extends Model
{
//
public $streampath;
public $converted;


protected $fillable = ['streampath', 'converted'];

/**
 * Video constructor.
 * @param array $path
 */
public function __construct($path=null)
{
    parent::__construct();
    if($path) {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

}
....
```

Here's the convert method:

```
    public function convert() {
        $uniqueId = $this->id;
        $tempPath = $this->path;
        $outputFileName = Carbon::now()->format('Ymdhis') . '.webm';
        $outputPath = 'videos/' . $outputFileName;
        $this->setConverted(ConvertStatusEnum::CONVERTING);
//        Run the converter
        $this->name = 'MY NEW TEST';
        $this->setStreampath($outputFileName);
        $this->setConverted(ConvertStatusEnum::CONVERTED);
        Log::debug($this);
        return $this;
    }
```

And here's the setters for those 2 properties:

```
public function setStreampath($streampath)
{
    $this->streampath = $streampath;
}
public function setConverted($converted)
{
    $this->converted = $converted;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You're returning `$this` at the end of your `convert()` method, but are you actually `save()`'ing the model? Also, you have two public properties named `$streampath` and `$converted`, why do these exist? If you end up saving the model, these changes won't appear in the database because their actual properties on the class itself. The `$fillable` array only dictates whether a **model attribute** can be filled, not a public property. I would heavily recommend reading up on models: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Comment: I am in the controller, but the issue doesn't seem to be the database being updated - when I log the model, those fields aren't set

Comment: @SteveBauman Removing those public properties seems to have done the trick - don't remember why those were added, must have been in error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change 
    `$this->property` 
To 
    `$this->attributes['property']`

Comment: Nope. The comment on my question fixed it